# Is there a word for this semi-continuity property?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Recall that $f$ is upper-semicontinuous if
$$ \text{for any } x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad f(x) \geq \inf_{\varepsilon > 0} \sup_{|y-x| < \varepsilon} f(y). \tag{$\dagger$}$$
Note that if $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f$ is obtained from $g$ by changing the value of $g$ at a single point, that is
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
g(x) &\text{ if } x \neq x_0, \\
y_0 &\text{ if } x = x_0,
\end{cases}
$$
where $y_0 > g(x_0)$, then $f$ is upper-semicontinuous. This strikes me as a slightly undesirable behaviour, since an upper-semicontinuous function cannot be reconstructed from its values at $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x_0\}$. Hence, I'm curious if there is an established name for the following stronger property:
$$ \text{for any } x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad f(x) = \inf_{\varepsilon > 0} \sup_{0<|y-x| < \varepsilon} f(y). \tag{$\ddagger$}$$
Any references would be highly appreciated. Note that I'm primarily interested in terminology that is already established, the task of coming up with a new name would be inherently opinion-based.

Comment: Do you really want equality in ($\ddagger)$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - Yes, I think so.

Comment: Just an observation: continuous functions satisfy this property, but the reverse implication is not true, since e.g. the function $f(x) = \sin(\frac1x)$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0) = 1$ also has this property.

Comment: @DejanGovc Thanks for the interesting example! The canonical example I had in mind are functions with jump discontinuities. Another non-trivial example is the characteristics function of anything that's closed and has no isolated points, such as the Cantor set. One can also construct a function that is strictly positive on all rationals and 0 elsewhere which satisfies the condition.